# index search in numpy fast

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm looking to grab values from one dataframe and append them to another based on index - and to do it *fast*. Lets say we have the following 2 dataframes:

`df` has a bunch of random numbers with cities as the column headers
`df2` is a dataframe full of cities with (unimportant) letters as the headers

In `df2` at position `df.loc[0,'c']` we have `Los Angeles`. I want to then go to `df` and find the `Los Angeles` column and take the value from the `0` index, and append it to `df2` so that it reads `Los Angeles : 544`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
cities = ['Minneapolis', 'Boston', 'Chicago', 'San Francisco', 'Los Angeles', 'Bozeman', 'New York', 'Austin',
                'Dallas', 'New Orleans']
df = pd.DataFrame({city:np.random.randint(1, 1000, 10000) for city in cities})
df = df.astype(str)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({k:[np.random.choice(cities) for i in range(10000)] for k in letters})

df
      Minneapolis  Boston  Chicago  San Francisco  Los Angeles
0             103     720      444            335          544
1             436     833      813            252          418
2             861     140      428            919          339
3             271     792       83            804          801
4             107     546      765            825          320

df2
                  a              b              c            d              e
0     San Francisco    Minneapolis    Los Angeles      Chicago    Los Angeles
1       Minneapolis  San Francisco    Los Angeles      Chicago  San Francisco
2       Minneapolis    Los Angeles         Boston      Chicago         Boston
3           Chicago        Chicago        Chicago       Boston    Los Angeles
4     San Francisco  San Francisco  San Francisco       Boston    Los Angeles
```

Expected Result:

df3

```
                        a                    b                    c  \
0     San Francisco : 335    Minneapolis : 103    Los Angeles : 544   
1       Minneapolis : 436  San Francisco : 252    Los Angeles : 418   
2       Minneapolis : 861    Los Angeles : 339         Boston : 140   
3            Chicago : 83         Chicago : 83         Chicago : 83   
4     San Francisco : 825  San Francisco : 825  San Francisco : 825
```

I solved this problem by doing a double for loop but it is taking too long since my dataframe is (280k, 260) and I have to do this function twice. I'm looking for a way in numpy to do this. Ideally if I can create a new numpy array where it has numbers as strings in the correct index locations, and I can use `np.char.add(df2, df)` to just add matrix-wise the words and numbers together. Just trying to figure out a quick way to index these values.

```
import time
s = time.time()
for col in df2.columns:
    for i in range(0, len(df2)):
        try:
            df2.loc[i, col] += ' : ' + str(np.round(df.loc[i, df2.loc[i, col]], 2))
        except:
            pass
print(time.time()-s)
16.95679211616516
```

Comment: so `len(df) == len(df2`? And you expecting `len(df3) == len(df)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, thats correct

Comment: @QuangHoang Edit - I lied, it isn't the same shape. I'm sorry. I just went back to review my actual code. the length is the same, but the columns are not.

Comment: I was asking specifically about the lengths. My answer doesn't expect equal numbers of columns either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lookup`:

```
s = df2.stack().reset_index(name='val');
df2 + ' : ' + df.lookup(s['level_0'], s['val']).reshape(df2.shape)
```

whose execution time on the 10000-row data is:

```
44 ms ± 1.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Output for the truncated data:

```
                     a                    b                    c  \
0  San Francisco : 335    Minneapolis : 103    Los Angeles : 544   
1    Minneapolis : 436  San Francisco : 252    Los Angeles : 418   
2    Minneapolis : 861    Los Angeles : 339         Boston : 140   
3         Chicago : 83         Chicago : 83         Chicago : 83   
4  San Francisco : 825  San Francisco : 825  San Francisco : 825   

               d                    e  
0  Chicago : 444    Los Angeles : 544  
1  Chicago : 813  San Francisco : 252  
2  Chicago : 428         Boston : 140  
3   Boston : 792    Los Angeles : 801  
4   Boston : 546    Los Angeles : 320
```

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you this worked perfectly! @QuangHoang